# Subset a data frame by randomly selecting values based on two columns

Tags: r, random, subset

I have a data frame that I want to subset by randomly selecting 25 values of ID based on `spp == cat` and 25 values of ID based on `spp == dog`.

Here is my example data:

```
ID  spp category    prop
1   cat small_mam   0.99
2   cat small_mam   0.8
2   cat birds       0.15
3   dog large_mam   1
4   dog med_mam     0.4
4   dog emu         0.6
10  dog med_mam     0.8
10  dog birds       0.2
12  dog reptiles    1
13  dog large_mam   1
14  dog large_mam   1
15  dog large_mam   1
27  cat birds       0.2
28  cat small_mam   1
29  cat small_mam   0.75
29  cat birds       0.25
30  cat small_mam   0.7
30  cat birds       0.2
```

ID values for spp are unique meaning that cat and dog never have the same ID value. ID ranges from 1 to 696 but is not necessarily unique, this is because ID can be composed of up to 7 categories so randomly sub-setting 25 rows for each species does not work.

The context behind this question is that I will be drawing 1000 random samples of 25 cat and 25 dog scats (UID = the scat ID number) for a bootstrap calculation of dietary overlap using the piankabio function in package(pgirmess).

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am using R version 3.1.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) you could do it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
subdf <- setDT(mydf)[, sample(ID, 5), by = spp]
```

On the example data you provided this gives:

> ```
> > subdf
>     spp V1
>  1: cat 27
>  2: cat 30
>  3: cat  2
>  4: cat 28
>  5: cat 30
>  6: dog 10
>  7: dog 14
>  8: dog 12
>  9: dog  4
> 10: dog 15
> ```

When you want to keep all columns (which I suppose you want to), you can do:

```
subdf <- setDT(mydf)[, .SD[sample(.N, 5)], by = spp]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > subdf
>     spp ID  category prop
>  1: cat 29 small_mam 0.75
>  2: cat  1 small_mam 0.99
>  3: cat  2     birds 0.15
>  4: cat 30 small_mam 0.70
>  5: cat 28 small_mam 1.00
>  6: dog 14 large_mam 1.00
>  7: dog 15 large_mam 1.00
>  8: dog 13 large_mam 1.00
>  9: dog 10     birds 0.20
> 10: dog  4   med_mam 0.40
> ```

---

*Note: I used a sample of 5 for explanatory reasons as the example dataset is not large enough to draw a sample of 25.*

---

In respons to your comment, you can achieve that with:

```
setDT(mydf)
set.seed(4321)
newdf <- mydf[mydf[, .(ID = sample(unique(ID), 5)), by = spp], on = c("spp", "ID")]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > newdf
>     ID spp  category prop
>  1: 27 cat     birds 0.20
>  2: 29 cat small_mam 0.75
>  3: 29 cat     birds 0.25
>  4:  2 cat small_mam 0.80
>  5:  2 cat     birds 0.15
>  6:  1 cat small_mam 0.99
>  7: 28 cat small_mam 1.00
>  8: 14 dog large_mam 1.00
>  9: 13 dog large_mam 1.00
> 10: 15 dog large_mam 1.00
> 11:  4 dog   med_mam 0.40
> 12:  4 dog       emu 0.60
> 13: 12 dog  reptiles 1.00
> ```

*Explanation*: With `mydf[, .(ID = sample(unique(ID), 5)), by = spp]` you create an index *data.table* with 5 unique ID's for each category of `spp`. Then you do a join on `spp` & `ID` where you use this index-data.table to select the part of `mydf` with these ID's.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need, the only issue is that this always only returns 50 rows (if I use 25 instead of 5).  What I actually need is that if an ID value is chosen that is not unique (because there can be multiple categories for an ID value), then I need all of the rows with that ID value returned in the subset. Each ID value corresponds to an individual scat and I need the subset to represent 25 cat scats and 25 dog scats so the subset data frames will likely be greater then 50 rows. I hope this makes sense. I realize that this probably wasn't clear from the original post.

Comment: yes, this does exactly what I need! Very much appreciated, thanks!